# How to install MonoDevelop 2.2 on Ubuntu 9.10?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mono-framework, monodevelop

Unfortunately there isn't a `.deb` on the monodevelop download page. Is there a way to install it on Ubuntu 9.10 without compiling from source? Has anyone uploaded it to a PPA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the most updated PPA that seems to be official: https://launchpad.net/~directhex/+archive/monoxide

Comment: Unfortunately, that PPA hasn't been updated in a while, the monodevelop in there is only 2.1

Comment: They updated the packages: take a look!

Comment: Comment from OP: That did not help since that PPA has the version 2.1.1 of Monodevelop which is 2.2 Beta2. Hopefully the PPA will get updated.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same thing, so I updated the monoxide packages to 2.2 and put them up on my ppa. I've only done some minimal testing, but they seem to work so far.

https://launchpad.net/~clayt055/+archive/ppa/+packages